# Did "Pokédex" recently become a slang term for iPhone?

Tags: slang, technology

Suddenly everyone is calling their iPhone a "pokédex". And not just comments in reddit.  Actual industry people. How did I miss this?

Comment: Can you include a link showing someone using "Pokedex" to refer to their iPhone?  My Google search overwhelmingly found "Pokedex" to be the name of a database for "Pokémon" characters.

Comment: You seem to be answering your own question. I did not know the term but if you know that "industry people" are using it then, obviously, _pokedex_ has recently become a slang term for _iPhone_. As for how you missed it, that is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: What @Kristina said. Who are these "everyone"? This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an extremely rare/non-existent slang usage.

Comment: I’d never heard the term before either, but I came across it a few hours ago. Didn’t we have a question about that (seeing/hearing/learning something for the first time, and then having it crop up again and again within five minutes) just a few days ago?

Comment: Is anyone chasing you around with a little red and white ball?

Comment: I've answered this question, but I'm wondering whether it's too localized.

Comment: Poor reception?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Blame xkcd. The [comic for November 8, 2013](http://xkcd.com/1288/) featured a list of "substitutions that make reading the news more fun".

[image: Substitutions That Make Reading the News More Fun - xkcd comic for Nov. 8, 2013]

Comment: So that's **today's** comic which "has been adopted by actual industry people" **within *hours***. Wow.

Comment: @Andrew: it's xkcd. Of course it was adopted within hours. :)

Comment: No, I realized soon after I posted this question that I installed a browser  extension that made all these substitutions automatically and FORGOT!  I successfully trolled myself and deserve all the downvotes you can give me.

Comment: @SanJacinto: there you go, ruining my perfectly-constructed dream world with pesky *facts*. Harumph.

Comment: Related:  http://xkcd.com/1037/  "Umwelt is the idea that because their senses pick up on different things, different animals in the same ecosystem actually live in very different worlds. Everything about you shapes the world you inhabit--from your ideology to your glasses prescription to your choice of web browser"  and now I can add "to your choice of web browser extension"